# App closes after clicking a button instead of returning to main activity

Tags: java, android

I am using  startActivityForResult() [in MainActivity class] to call another activity called "EditActivity" & get some edited values back to the MainActivity. EditActivity has a button which when pressed should return the user to the MainActivity. But instead the app is closing on button-press.
Inside MainActivity :

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, EditActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("edit_data", arrayList.get(position).toString());
            intent.putExtra("edit_position", position);
            startActivityForResult(intent, IntentValuesClass.REQUEST_CODE);
        }


    });
```

Inside EditActivity:

```
   saveButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent data=new Intent();
                    data.putExtra("edited_text",editInput);
                    data.putExtra("position",pos);
                    setResult(EditActivity.RESULT_OK,data);
                    Log.w(IntentValuesClass.Msg,"Button SAVE Clicked");
                    finish();
                    Log.w(IntentValuesClass.Msg,"finished");
                }
            }
    );
```

Again on returning to MainActivity:

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
       Log.w(IntentValuesClass.Msg,"Inside onActivityResult");
        int position;
        if (requestCode == IntentValuesClass.REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode==EditActivity.RESULT_OK) {
                Log.w(IntentValuesClass.Msg,"Result ok");
                String s = data.getStringExtra("edited_text");
                position = data.getIntExtra("position",-1);
                arrayList.remove(position);
                arrayList.add(position, s);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: post error log here

Comment: And place a breakpoint in the item clicked method and step through Post any deviation from what you expect

Comment: Your app probably crashed, check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this/23353174#23353174 and include stacktrace in your question.

Comment: @AkhileshPatil logcat is showing no error

Answer (score 1):

put the `finish()` at the end of your method.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent data=new Intent();
    data.putExtra("edited_text",editInput);
    data.putExtra("position",pos);
    setResult(EditActivity.RESULT_OK,data);
    Log.w(IntentValuesClass.Msg,"Button SAVE Clicked");
    Log.w(IntentValuesClass.Msg,"finished");
    finish();
}
```